# SoftdeleteBehavior but still getting deleted instances

Tags: cakephp, cakedc

I'm trying to use the cakeDC/utils SoftdeleteBehavior, to allow users to restore deleted instances of a model.

The soft deletion is working fine so far, but I also want to be able to view
a deleted instance of the model.

I tried to find the instance with findById($id), but it calls the beforeFind method of the behavior which checks for `deleted = true` and thus doesn't return the instance.

Is there any other way to retrieve it without using SQL directly?

edit: I'm using cakephp-2.4.9

Comment: Please always mention your exact CakePHP version!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to temporary [**disable the behavior**](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/behaviors.html#using-behaviors) for that specific find call, something like

```
$enabled = $YourModel->Behaviors->enabled('SoftDelete');
if($enabled) {
    $YourModel->Behaviors->disable('SoftDelete');
}

$result = $YourModel->findById($id);

if($enabled) {
    $YourModel->Behaviors->enable('SoftDelete');
}
```

From looking at the code it should also be possible to explicitly retrieve a record by its flag state, ie something like

```
$YourModel->findByIdAndDeleted($id, true);
```

might work too. However, whether this is applicable of course depends on your specific use case.

Comment: The second method is not applicable, because I want both - deleted and not deleted - to be found.
Temporarily disabling the behavior works though, I didn't know that works :).